# Using or_comm in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to prove the following theorem:

```
Theorem T14 : forall s t u,
  S u s t <-> S u t s.
```

Where `S` is defined like this:

```
Definition S u s t := forall v,
  ((ObS u v) <-> (ObS v s \/ ObS v t)).
```

The first tactics I used are:

```
Proof.
  intros s t u.
  unfold S.
```

And my goal is now:

```
1 subgoal
s, t, u : Entity
______________________________________(1/1)
(forall v : Entity, ObS u v <-> ObS v s \/ ObS v t) <->
(forall v : Entity, ObS u v <-> ObS v t \/ ObS v s)
```

It feels like the proof can be finished if I use the commutativity of the OR operator, and then apply the `tauto` tactic. However, I don't know how to rewrite the inner bit of only the right part of the equivalence. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using generalized rewriting.

1. `Require Setoid.`
2. Use `setoid_rewrite` because you are rewriting under a binder (`forall v`). (Without binders, `rewrite` would be sufficient).

It works out-of-the-box in this case, but when your project gets more sophisticated, with your own combinators/logical connectives, some work will be necessary to ensure that "rewriting" is sound. [The reference manual describes the set up required by generalized rewriting.](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html)

```
(* 1 *)
Require Import Setoid.

Parameter T : Type.
Parameter ObS : T -> T -> Prop.

Definition S u s t := forall v,
  ((ObS u v) <-> (ObS v s \/ ObS v t)).

Theorem T14 : forall s t u,
  S u s t <-> S u t s.
Proof.
  intros s t u.
  unfold S.
  (* 2 *)
  setoid_rewrite (or_comm (ObS _ s)).
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```